# How can I display a users profile to another user with in FOUserbundle in Symfony4?

Tags: php, symfony, user-controls, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I want to FOSUserBundle show user profile by id/username Like **profile/username/edit**

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a route that takes username or id and resolves it to a particular user. This can be done using a [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) or just "manually" inside your controller.

The following snippets tries to find a user by its username:

```
/*
 * @Route("/profiles/{username}")
 * @ParamConverter("user", class="User", options={"mapping": {"username": "username"}})
 */
public function userProfile(User $user)
{
    return $this->render('user_profile.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```